# Weird exception on rollback transaction

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a shared method on a library that executes all SQL queries as parameters, but one day a exception was generated when this method tried to rollback a query that always work normally. The exception was

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

The method is pretty simple, like this:

```
Dim auxConnectionSB As New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
With auxConnectionSB
    .InitialCatalog = ""
    .DataSource = ""
    .UserID = ""
    .Password = ""
    .Pooling = ""
End With
Using auxConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(auxConnectionSB.ToString)
    Try
        auxConnection.Open()
        Using auxTransaction = auxConnection.BeginTransaction
            Try
                For Each query In querys
                    Dim auxCommand = auxConnection.CreateCommand
                    auxCommand.CommandText = query
                    auxCommand.Transaction = auxTransaction
                    auxCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                auxTransaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                auxTransaction.Rollback()
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CustomSqlException(auxConnection, ex)
    End Try
End Using
```

Seeing information on SQL traces, the query had the status "Aborted", so the `ExecuteNonQuery` did throw an exception (maybe a Timeout, but took 34 seconds, and the default timeout is 30 seconds), so activated the Rollback instruction, but generated the exception mentioned previously.

Seeing information on my `CustomSqlException`, the Connection was in a closed status when tried to do the Rollback, but my code does not close connections explicitly, so I don't know how the connection was closed.

What else should I review to understand this problem? Or which information should add to SQL traces/VB code to understand this problem in a future?

Comment: Presumably the command was aborted because the connection was unexpectedly closed, maybe because of network issues, and a transaction cannot be rolled back over a closed connection.  If the connection is lost when a transaction is in progress, (I think) the database instance should automatically rollback the transaction.  I guess that you should, in theory, check that the connection is still open before rolling back explicitly.

Comment: hi @jmcilhinney, I think network issues are weird because the code that uses that method is a web application, and the database instance is running on the same machine. As I read, I should validate that the transaction is not "zombied", or simply omit rollback because is automatically rolledback the transaction when the connection is disposed by the using method. Anyway I want to add more information to be prepared in case the problem becomes recurrent.